# Como mostrar corretamente a paginação?

Tags: php, mysql

Fiz uma parte do meu sistema de paginação mas ele sempre mostra o numero máximo de produtos no meu banco sendo que na busca eu especifiquei o nome.

Tipo eu faço a busca por Leonardo ai no meu banco tem Leonardo cadastrado e mais 8 pessoas ai ele me traz o Leonardo como primeiro e continua mostrando sem nada as li da paginação com os números como posso arrumar isso para buscar pelo o que o cara digitar no formulário de busca?

Meu código é este:

```
<?php
require_once("classe/conexao.class.php");
$c = new Conexao();
$c->conecta();
// inicia paginacao
$totalProduto = 1;
$pagina = (@isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina']: 1;
$inicio = ($totalProduto * $pagina) - $totalProduto;

$busca = $_GET['q'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' OR categoria LIKE '%$busca%' ORDER BY id_produto LIMIT $inicio, $totalProduto");
if(empty($_GET['q'])){
    echo"<script>alert('Nenhum Resultado Encontrado'), window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    exit();
}
while($registro = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $nome = $registro['nome'];
    $categoria = $registro['categoria'];
    $descricao = $registro['descricao'];
    $preco = $registro['preco'];
    $img = $registro['img'];
    $id = $registro['id_produto'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

    print"
        <div class=\"col-sm-4\">
            <div class=\"product-image-wrapper\">
                <div class=\"single-products\">
                        <div class=\"productinfo text-center\">
                            <img src=\"images/shop/$img\" alt=\"$nome\" width=\"694\" height=\"300\" />
                            <h2>R$ $preco</h2>
                            <p>$nome</p>
                            <a href=\"detalhe.php?cod=$id\" class=\"btn btn-default add-to-cart\"><i class=\"fa fa-shopping-cart\"></i>Detalhes</a>
                        </div>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>";
}//fim while

$sqlTotal = "SELECT id_produto FROM produtos";
$qrTotal = mysql_query($sqlTotal) or die (mysql_error());
$numTotal = mysql_num_rows($qrTotal);
$totalPagina = ceil($numTotal/$totalProduto);
?>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
<?php              
echo"
<ul class=\"pagination\">
<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"?pagina=1&q=$busca\">Primeira Pagina</a></li>
</ul>

";
for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPagina; $i++){
    if($i == $pagina)
    echo "
    <ul class=\"pagination\">
        <li class=\"active\"><a hreaf=".$i.">$i</a></li>
    </ul>";
    else
    echo"
    <ul class=\"pagination\">
    <li><a href=\"?pagina=$i&q=$busca\">$i</a></li>
    </ul>
    ";
};

        mysql_close();
    ?>
```